# Computer exercises and solutions in signal processing

Tags: signal-analysis, reference-request, self-study

I am very interested in this question and can literally not find anywhere a simple answer, so apologize in advance if it does not fit well this community.

I am looking for either an online resource or a book with computer exercises and solutions in signal processing (can be really anything in this space). I am interested in practicing independently, and while there are countless sources for practice computer exercises, I could not find any source that has solutions as well. Don't mind buying a $100 text book if needed. Appreciate any help in this direction.

Answer (score 4):

["Digital Signal Processing: A Computer-Based Approach"](https://books.google.com/books/about/Digital_Signal_Processing.html?id=nCFdkgEACAAJ&hl=en)  by Sanjit Mitra is what you need I guess, especially the exercises at the end of each chapter. There is a booklet on the Internet again by Mitra, named [Digital Signal Processing **Laboratory** Using MATLAB](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071165924).
The other option could be [Practical Signals Theory with MATLAB Applications](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-EHEP002523.html).

Comment: Does it have solutions too?

Comment: @moshikafya , I guess so, but I can not remeber, since it was long ago I studied his books. Google "solution manual for ....".

Answer (score 3):

Signal Processing is a very broad area,  you might want to down select a bit.

For speech processing,

L. R. Rabiner and R. W. Schafer, "Matlab exercises in support of teaching digital speech processing," 2014 IEEE International Conference on Acoustics, Speech and Signal Processing (ICASSP), Florence, 2014, pp. 2480-2483 [[link]](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4581/140d04406e58db96907a3211b89f1362dffd.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like a paper rather than a set of problems with solutions, unless I am missing something? And yes, I don't mind which subject within signal processing as I mentioned. Speech processing works too.

Comment: They have a text book which I thought they referred to. I haven't looked at the book but Rabiner and Schafer are Signal Processing foundational figures. One might say royalty with a small r. If they say they have 58 problems they have 58 problems

Answer (score 2):

You can check out ThinkDSP if you're okay with implementing DSP stuff using Python. You can get the book for free [here](http://greenteapress.com/thinkdsp/thinkdsp.pdf)  and the associated code [here](https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkDSP)